# Set/Get value to Stateful Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a text field in my widget.  I want to refresh it when I get some update from the server.  Right now I do

```
  setState(() {
    _msg = "new message";
  });
```

and it rebuilds my whole widget.  I would like to do

```
  _msg.set("new message");
```

it should call setState inside the _msg widget and rebuild only _msg.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not directly, no. Actually the rebuild is not an inefficient operation. State is a simple data structure and for parts of it that did not change, the actual UI elements behind them are not recreated. If you really wanted to get rid of rebuilds for some reason, I think the Provider widget has ways to make the relevant widgets listen to changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a stateful widget. This will allow you to update the widget state using `setState((){})`.

When you call `setState((){})` it will rebuild the stateful widget it is within. The entire widget will get rebuild. Don't worry, rebuilding the entire widget again. For example:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { .... will get rebuilt ....}
```

It looks like _msg is a type String. If you want to update the String text, calling `setState((){})` will accomplish this goal. Here is a quick example where you can see a text field changing in the AppBar title and also the console through print. Happy coding.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String _msg = "first message";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyWidget: _msg = $_msg'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
        print('before setState _msg = $_msg');
        setState(() {
          _msg = 'second message';
          print('after setState _msg = $_msg');
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing now.

Comment: if this is the correct answer, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: It is not.  It is what I was doing before asking this question.

Comment: can you provide more code in your question so the SO community can help you?